# vue2-datepicker how to check for value with blur (or any other event)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

With the following, how can I detect a change with `@blur` to check the value of the input if someone has has clicked away from the datepicker with/without selecting the date?

```
<date-picker
        id="endTimeInput"
        name="endTime"
        ref="endTime"
        :time-picker-options="{start: '00:00', end: '23:45', step: '00:30'}"
        data-vv-as="End Time"
        v-model="entity.currentMilestone.endTime" lang="en" type="time"
        v-if="entity.currentMilestone.endTime || showEndTime"
        @blur="checkEndTime"
        placeholder="Select end time"
        format="HH:mm"
        value-format="HH:mm"
        class="col-sm-9 custom-timepicker">
</date-picker>
```

For context, this is how I focus the cursor on the input field for the date-picker.

`this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.endTime.$el.querySelector("input").focus())`

```js
checkEndTime(e) {
    console.log('value:', e.target.value)
},
```

The above function prints an empty string even if I select a time.

Comment: Can you log to the console only `e`?

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov the event is logged. However, navigating to e > target > value shows an empty string ""

Comment: What if you use `this.$refs.input`?

Comment: you mean console log `this.$refs.input` or use it to focus? Using it to focus returns an undefined error

Comment: Have you tried `change` and `input` methods to see if they work?

Comment: yes they both do not respond to a 'blur' event

Comment: I mean instead of `blur` try `change`. `@change="checkEndTime"`

Comment: could you please upload this in JSFiddle?

Comment: yes i tried both `change` and `input`, they both do not give me the effect I want (which is a blur effect) or rather they do not listen when user clicks away

Comment: You can check this `entity.currentMilestone.endTime` instead of checking `input value`.

Comment: That's the issue I'm having. I am struggling to set `entity.currentMilestone.endTime` when user selects / or does not select time. It only does that after I save the whole object/entity.

Comment: I think you shold check out the `date-picker.vue` component. I see there everything you need to solve your problem. https://github.com/mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker/blob/master/src/date-picker.vue